# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error for using Switch statement?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, mach-o

I am creating an Objective-C program that when calling a C function, it will try to convert a number and return a string. However this caused an Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error when I tried to compile.

Here's the code snippet:

```
NSString * convertNum (int theNum) {
  NSString *numString;

  switch (theNum) {
    case 102:
       numString = @"Oh yea, string 102";
       break;
    case 104:
       numString = @"Oh great, string 104";
       break;
    /* ... */
    default:
       numString = @"Don't feed me with something I don't know!";
       break;
  }

  return numString;
}
```

Did I do anything wrong? I am using Xcode 4. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the error? Also, you're not specifying a type for `theNum`.

Comment: Isn't this a classic dangling pointer problem? NumString is only valid within the scope of the function, it would be illegal to use the returned pointer outside.

Comment: Sorry! I was being careless. The error is "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error", which also gave me this when I double-clicked the error in the Issue navigator.clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Compiles, links, and runs fine for me.  The error must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Go to the extended build log and find the full error message;  there will be more than just that.

Comment: @talonmies Nope -- that code is fine.

Comment: Hello, first of all, thanks for the help! This error is gone when I imported the .h containing the code above to the App Delegate instead of the .h file of a class. It's solved I believe, but I still do not understand why it happened. Any help would be appreciated. Once again, thank you!

Comment: As declared, that code should *not be in a .h*.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Now I understand what had happened. Sorry for my ignorance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking error usually means something like a method, function or something similar has the prototype declare but it is not implemented anywhere. It can also mean you have not included a library or framework in you application but you are using the header files from that library or framework.

Also your use of numString is fine, you are returning pointers to strings that are static, they generated at compile time.